# using three buttons in row

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I have listView has rows every row should have three buttons

but I want each button has unique text as list of String has .

I have tried that code but it gives me the following result

```
1   1   1

2   2   2

3   3   3
```

but I want such that :

```
1   2   3

4   5   6

7   8   9
```

myclass code :

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rep2, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.Button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button01);

            viewHolder.Button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button02);

            viewHolder.Button3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button03);

            // viewHolder.row = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.TableRow06);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.row.setTag(ClassList.get(position));

            viewHolder.Button1.setTag(ClassList.get(position));

            viewHolder.Button2.setTag(ClassList.get(position));

            viewHolder.Button3.setTag(ClassList.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;

            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).Button1
                    .setTag(ClassList.get(position));

            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).Button2
                    .setTag(ClassList.get(position));

            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).Button3
                    .setTag(ClassList.get(position));

            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).row.setTag(ClassList.get(position));

        }
```

Layout xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/classes" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/classes" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/classes" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'ts just list contains Strings . it's works but i want buttons getting 1234567 each row has 3 buttons only no duplicate values

Comment: Try to use `GridView` it will give you exactly that result what you want.

Comment: GridView works only with api 14 so i'm uses api 9

Comment: Use the support-library then

Comment: `GridView`, added in API level 1

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Answer (score 0):

In `get()` the `position` is the position in the `ListView`, not the position of each particular `View` in the row. This means that in the first cycle you are always passing 0 to `ClassList` through `get()` so it is always returning the value of the first `index` (1).

If these are the only values you will have then you could create 3 different `Arrays` with the 3 `int`s and decide which `Array` to use based off of the `position` using a `switch` statement.

You could also use the `position` to decide where to start in the `Array` and increase the value by one in a `for loop` each time to get the next value for each of the 3 `Button`s.

**Edit**

```
switch position
{
    case 0:
       button1.setTag(Class.get(0);
       button2.setTag(Class.get(1);
       button3.setTag(Class.get(2);
       break;
    case 1:
       button1.setTag(Class.get(3);
       button2.setTag(Class.get(4);
       button3.setTag(Class.get(5);
       break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i know that , but you answer not helping me , my Q is : how to make it return for every button it's right string without duplicate values , and in same time using three buttons in every row .

Comment: if you know that, why yre you trying the get(position) of the View then? :)

Comment: It didn't seem as though you understood *why* it was happening. I have given a couple options with that you have.

Comment: i'm using get(position) cuz i want every button has unique value or text according to it's get(position).getname()

Comment: i don't use three arrays , i'm just have one array or list of strings . i want to fill up the row with three buttons each buttons must get his unique value from my list depending with get pos

Comment: Yes, we understand what you are trying to do. See my edit if you will only have the 3 rows. If it will be dynamic then you will need to create a variable and assign that a variable according to the `position`. Then increase that number by whatever you need. That's the best I can come up with for now.

Comment: No , you didn't understand me , i have list of int s from 1 to n .. so i don't have fixed number of rows! in the same time i have only three buttons in each row , so i want button one in row one has value " a " , button 2 in row one has value " b " , button three in row one has value " c " , button four in row two! has value " d " and so on , note : my list of int s i'm getting it's value from database . and the listview each time increasing the pos by one automatically i don't need to use for loop

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are the same because each row contains three buttons, so you are setting their text to what position they are on. Since 1 row hasthree buttons, position will always be the same for each button. You have to switch on your position and change the values accordingly.

EDIT: Are you going to have a fixed number of ListView items are will it vary?

Comment: No , my list of strings has number of strings i don't know how many . but i have three buttons in each row .

Answer (score 0):

Take a variable called cntr=0 in your adapter class and set the values as

```
 viewHolder.Button1.setTag(ClassList.get(cntr++));

  viewHolder.Button2.setTag(ClassList.get(cntr++));
     viewHolder.Button3.setTag(ClassList.get(cntr++));
```

Remember cntr should be a class variable assigned only once

Comment: not working , i want to assign to every button i have his correct value without duplicate and each row must have three buttons